# Python Pandas: Convert Rows as Column headers

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
Year    Country          medal    no of medals
1896    Afghanistan      Gold        5
1896    Afghanistan      Silver      4
1896    Afghanistan      Bronze      3
1896    Algeria          Gold        1
1896    Algeria          Silver      2
1896    Algeria          Bronze      3
```

I want it this way.

```
Year    Country      Gold   Silver   Bronze
1896    Afghanistan    5      4         3
1896    Algeria        1      2         3
```

Stack/Unstack dont seem to work.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

You're looking for [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.tools.pivot.pivot_table.html):

```
In [11]: medals = df.pivot_table('no of medals', ['Year', 'Country'], 'medal')

In [12]: medals
Out[12]:
medal             Bronze  Gold  Silver
Year Country
1896 Afghanistan       3     5       4
     Algeria           3     1       2
```

and if you want to reorder the columns:

```
In [12]: medals.reindex_axis(['Gold', 'Silver', 'Bronze'], axis=1)
Out[12]:
medal             Gold  Silver  Bronze
Year Country
1896 Afghanistan     5       4       3
     Algeria         1       2       3
```

Comment: This creates a multilevel index, which is not 100% what was wanted. Get rid of it by `medals.reset_index( drop=False, inplace=True )` then follow by `medals.reindex_axis(['Year', 'Country', 'Gold', 'Silver', 'Bronze'], axis=1)`

Comment: Python v3.6+  `'.reindex_axis' is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use '.reindex' instead.`

Answer (score 15):

Stack/ Unstack won't work until you have the desired column in your row/ column indexes. e.g. In simple words, Stack/ Unstack will bring the lowest level of column index to the lowest level of row index and vice versa.

So in your case, you can achieve the same results with stack/unstack via:

```py
df.set_index(['Year','Country','medal'], drop=True).unstack('medal')
```

[image]