# How to combine multiple rows to extra columns in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
    c1 c2  c3
0   1  A  11
1   1  B  12
2   2  A  21
3   2  B  22
```

Now I want to transform it to a new dataframe like

```
    c1   A   B
0   1  11  12
1   2  21  22
```

How can I achieve this with pandas?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in another question: [python-pandas-convert-rows-as-column-headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298313/python-pandas-convert-rows-as-column-headers).
Just use [pivot_table](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html)