# Pandas: transform column's values in independent columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have Pandas DataFrame which looks like following (`df_olymic`).
I would like the values of column `Type` to be transformed in independent columns (`df_olympic_table`)

Original dataframe

```
In [3]: df_olympic
Out[3]: 
   Country    Type Num
0      USA    Gold  46
1      USA  Silver  37
2      USA  Bronze  38
3       GB    Gold  27
4       GB  Silver  23
5       GB  Bronze  17
6    China    Gold  26
7    China  Silver  18
8    China  Bronze  26
9   Russia    Gold  19
10  Russia  Silver  18
11  Russia  Bronze  19
```

Transformed dataframe

```
In [5]: df_olympic_table
Out[5]: 
  Country N_Gold N_Silver N_Bronze
0     USA     46       37       38
1      GB     27       23       17
2   China     26       18       26
3  Russia     19       18       19
```

What would be the most convenient way to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Pandas: Convert Rows as Column headers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298313/python-pandas-convert-rows-as-column-headers)

Comment: Sorry, I might abuse pandas common terminology. Still keep learning :-)

Comment: @Aprillion - `pivot_table` is not necessary, if not duplicates better is  `pivot`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df = df.pivot(index='Country', columns='Type', values='Num')
print (df)
Type     Bronze  Gold  Silver
Country                      
China        26    26      18
GB           17    27      23
Russia       19    19      18
USA          38    46      37
```

Another solution with [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['Country','Type'])['Num'].unstack()
print (df)
Type     Bronze  Gold  Silver
Country                      
China        26    26      18
GB           17    27      23
Russia       19    19      18
USA          38    46      37
```

but if get:

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

need [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) with some aggreagte function, by default it is `np.mean`, but you can use `sum`, `first`...

```
#add new row with duplicates value in 'Country' and 'Type'
print (df)
   Country    Type  Num
0      USA    Gold   46
1      USA  Silver   37
2      USA  Bronze   38
3       GB    Gold   27
4       GB  Silver   23
5       GB  Bronze   17
6    China    Gold   26
7    China  Silver   18
8    China  Bronze   26
9   Russia    Gold   19
10  Russia  Silver   18
11  Russia  Bronze   20 < - changed value to 20
11  Russia  Bronze  100 < - add new row with duplicates


df = df.pivot_table(index='Country', columns='Type', values='Num', aggfunc=np.mean)
print (df)
Type     Bronze  Gold  Silver
Country                      
China        26    26      18
GB           17    27      23
Russia       60    19      18 < - Russia get ((100 + 20)/ 2 = 60
USA          38    46      37
```

Or [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with aggreagting [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html) and reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['Country','Type'])['Num'].mean().unstack()
print (df)
Type     Bronze  Gold  Silver
Country                      
China        26    26      18
GB           17    27      23
Russia       60    19      18 < - Russia get ((100 + 20)/ 2 = 60
USA          38    46      37
```

Comment: Perfect! You really made me learn something new. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, it is more complicated if duplicates. Thanks for accepting!

Comment: @ade1e - yes, I changed data for add duplicates, so I add notice to changed rows.