# i want to convert dataframe into specific formated dataframe or list of lists

Tags: python

this is the Dataframe

```
Year    Category    Performance
2014    Sales           1000
2014    Expenses        400
2014    Profit          200
2015    Sales           1170
2015    Expenses        460
2015    Profit          250
2016    Sales           660
2016    Expenses        1120
2016    Profit          300
```

And this is the expected output

```
 [          
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses', 'Profit'],          
          ['2014', 1000, 400, 200],         
          ['2015', 1170, 460, 250],         
          ['2016', 660, 1120, 300],                     
        ]
```

or if you could help me to convert this dataframe into this

```
Year Sales Expenses Profit      
2014 1000  400       200        
2015 1170  460       250        
2016 660   1120      300
```

Comment: Looks like a duplicate to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298313/python-pandas-convert-rows-as-column-headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.pivot_table(df, index='Year', columns='Category', values='Performence').reset_index()
```

Comment: Code only answers can be helpful, but 99% of the time they are better if you add some explanation. Could you describe what your code does to help readers understand it?

Comment: @3limin4t0r I don't think a simple one-line one-function (and I don't count `reset_index()` as a real function) needs explainations. If someone doesn't understand a function, he can simply google it.