# Modify Dataframe based on Priority

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a df like this:

```
ID   A1    A2     A3    A4    A5
1    1            2            3
2    1     2             3
3    2     1 
4    3            1            2
5
```

For every ID, I have 5 columns A1 to A5 (In real I have many more) and the values are top priority for a particular ID.

**For example**: ID 1 has A1, A3 and A5 as priorites, , ID 3 has only 2 A2 and A1 and ID 5 has no
Priorities

**Resultant DF**

```
ID Priority_1  Priority_2  Priority_3
1    A1            A3         A5
2    A1            A2         A4
3    A2            A1   
4    A3            A5         A1
5
```

I am trying to same using `melt` and `pivot` using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28654047/pandas-convert-some-columns-into-rows) and [this_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298313/python-pandas-convert-rows-as-column-headers) and many more, but exactly not able to get the same resultant df.

Any help on this or clarity from my side!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with sorting by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and removing missing rows by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html), then add new column used for filtering by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and [`Series.le`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.le.html) for `less or equal` and last use [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html), last add [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for added only mising rows `ID`:

```
N = 3
df1 = df.melt('ID').sort_values(['ID','value']).dropna(subset=['value'])
df1['new'] = df1.groupby('ID').cumcount().add(1)
df1 = df1[df1['new'].le(N)]

df2 = df1.pivot('ID','new','variable').add_prefix('Priority_').reindex(df['ID'])
print (df2)
new Priority_1 Priority_2 Priority_3
ID                                  
1           A1         A3         A5
2           A1         A2         A4
3           A2         A1        NaN
4           A3         A5         A1
5          NaN        NaN        NaN
```

Comment: Thanks!! I can have a result where there is ID 5 also with all "NaN"