# Converting python dataframe into proper row column format

Tags: python-3.x

I have  dataframe like this

```
field_id    field_name       field_value
4           Rate                  40
5           Rate                  35
4           Duration              60
5           Duration              180
```

I want to convert it into something like this

```
id    Rate        Duration
4       40           60
5       35           180
```

How can I do this in python ? Please help

Comment: can you paste in table format?

Comment: You may post a snapshot (copy snapshot and paste in the editor) or explore the editor for better formatting your input

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Pandas: Convert Rows as Column headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298313/python-pandas-convert-rows-as-column-headers)

Comment: @BernadPeter I have added images for reference

Comment: @JALO-JusAnotherLivngOrganism In the example that you mentioned, I want to make country values as column names(Afghanistan , Algeria etc), medal and no. of medals as its values. That is what I am trying to do

Answer (score 0):

You can use pivot tables function

```
print(df)
field_id    field_name  field_value
0   4   Rate    40
1   5   Rate    35
2   4   Duration    60
3   5   Duration    180

df['field_value']=df['field_value'].astype('int64')
df1=df.pivot_table(index='field_id',columns='field_name',values='field_value')
df1
#output: 
field_name  Duration    Rate
field_id        
4   60  40
5   180 35
```

Comment: I am getting this error DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

Comment: make sure your column dtype is int64 for the filed_value column. if not use use astype to convert to int format.

Comment: field_name and field_value is of type object right now and field_id is int64

Comment: use  this command to change to numeric: see the updated code

Comment: @ BernadPeter    I am getting this ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.0'

Comment: it is difficult to understand your problem without looking into the full dataframe info and dtypes

Comment: @ BernadPeter  okay.. Will let you know all the information

Answer (score 0):

I did it the more easier way out. Please try the below snippet.

```
mylist = df[fields].values.tolist()
```