# Pandas converting column values into row values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this :

```
id, name, comment
1, 'name',['string', 'string','string','string'] 
2, 'name',['stringx', 'stringy','stringz','stringx']
```

I want to convert this data frame to something that looks like this:

```
1, 'name', 'string'
1, 'name','string'
1, 'name', 'string'
1, 'name','string'
2, 'name', 'stringx'
2, 'name','stringy'
2, 'name', 'stringz'
2, 'name','stringx'
```

Comment: Checkout [`df.explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)

Comment: The answer is here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298313/python-pandas-convert-rows-as-column-headers

Comment: Is your comment column a `list` or `str` representation of a `list`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DataFrame.explode`

```py
df.explode('comment')
```

```
    id  name    comment
0   1   name    string
0   1   name    string
0   1   name    string
0   1   name    string
1   2   name    stringx
1   2   name    stringy
1   2   name    stringz
1   2   name    stringx
```