# Pandas convert columns to rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I am a beginner in Data Science and I am trying to pivot this data frame using Pandas:

[image]

So it becomes something like this: (The labels should become the column and file paths the rows.)

[image]

#### I tried this code which gave me an error:

[image]

### EDIT:

I have tried Marcel's suggestion, the output it gave is this:[image]

The "label" column is a group or class of file paths. I want to convert it in such a way it fits this function: [tf.Keras.preprocessing.image.flow_from_dataframe](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow_from_dataframe) in `categorical`

Thanks in advance to all for helping me out.

Comment: Do you have an equal size of paths for each label? If not, can you live with `nan`s?

Comment: Maybe, I haven't checked that yet, kindly provide your solution, I will check if it works.

Comment: See an example below with `nan`s below. Hope it helps.

Comment: Alright, let me check.

Answer (score 3):

I did not understand your question very well, but if you just want to convert columns to rows then you can do

```
train_df.T
```

which means transpose

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I want something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298313/python-pandas-convert-rows-as-column-headers

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'labels': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'],
    'pathes' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
})

labels = df['labels'].unique()
new_cols = []
for label in labels:
    new_cols.append(df['pathes'].where(df['labels'] == label).dropna().reset_index(drop=True))
df_final = pd.concat(new_cols, axis=1)

print(df_final)
```

Comment: Hi, I have shared my response in the edit. Kindly check it. I hope it would make sense now.

Answer (score 0):

I've found what was wrong, I misunderstood y_col and x_col in [tf.Keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_dataframe](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow_from_dataframe). Thanks to all of you for your contributions. Your answers are all correct in different ways. Thanks again [Marcel h](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13095767/marcel-h) and [user16714199](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16714199/user16714199)!