# Pandas: Create new columns with column name based on values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**I have this original dataframe:**

```
                     column  data
datetime                         
2021-01-23 00:01:00       1    10
2021-01-23 00:01:00       2    15
2021-01-23 00:02:00       1    11
2021-01-23 00:03:00       1    12
2021-01-23 00:03:00       2    14
```

- There may be more than one row with the same datetime, as illustrated in the example.
- There may be more than just the two different values in column `column`, this is a simplified example.
- All values are integers.

**I want to create this new dataframe:**

```
                      1    2
datetime                         
2021-01-23 00:01:00  10   15
2021-01-23 00:02:00  11  NaN
2021-01-23 00:03:00  12   14
```

**Actions needed:**

- For every unique value in column `column`, create a new column with the value as the name of the column.
- For every unique datetime, create a new row.
- Fill the values according the `data` column from the original dataframe, with NaN if there is no value.

**Code to create the original dataframe:**

```
import io, pandas as pd

t = io.StringIO("""
datetime|column|data
2021-01-23 00:01:00|1|10
2021-01-23 00:01:00|2|15
2021-01-23 00:02:00|1|11
2021-01-23 00:03:00|1|12
2021-01-23 00:03:00|2|14""")
df = pd.read_csv(t, sep='|', parse_dates=['datetime']).set_index('datetime').astype(int)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Bravo with the elegant  way of asking a question. This question is answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298313/python-pandas-convert-rows-as-column-headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pandas [pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) will help you

```
pd.pivot_table(df, values ='data', index =['datetime'],columns =['column']).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
        datetime         1       2
0   2021-01-23 00:01:00 10.0    15.0
1   2021-01-23 00:02:00 11.0    NaN
2   2021-01-23 00:03:00 12.0    14.0
```

Comment: Wow! The perfect answer in 1 minute and in 1 line. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it solves your issue.. kindly accept the answer and upvote :)

Comment: Hi Subbu. The best way is to mark a question as duplicate. There are extensive answers already in SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe