# Convert combinations of row+column as Column headers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
Machine    Time      Part    PowerA    PowerB
1         20:30       1        0.1      0.4
1         20:30       2        0.9      0.7
1         20:31       1        0.3      0.1
1         20:31       2        0.2      0.3
2         20:30       1        0.2      0.5
2         20:31       1        0.8      0.4
```

I want it to be like:

```
Machine    Time      Part1_PowerA   Part1_PowerB    Part2_PowerA    Part2_PowerB
1         20:30           0.1            0.4            0.9             0.7
1         20:31           0.3            0.1            0.2             0.3
2         20:30           0.2            0.5           -1.0            -1.0
2         20:31           0.8            0.4           -1.0            -1.0
```

The objective is that I create a column for each `Part` and `Power` and fill the values as shown. Each machine has a variable number of parts, but the maximum is 8 (which would lead to columns `Part8_PowerA` and `Part8_PowerB`). When a machine doesn't have a certain part, the values for the Part_Power are filled with -1.

I have looked quite a while for solutions, [including this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298313/python-pandas-convert-rows-as-column-headers), but I wasn't able to adapt to my situation, where I actually change the names of the columns as a combination of a row value + already existent column.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us do `pivot_table` then `swaplevel`

```
s = df.pivot_table(index= ['Machine','Time'], 
                   columns = df.Part.astype(str).radd('Part'),
                   values=['PowerA','PowerB'],
                   fill_value=-1).swaplevel(1,0, axis=1).sort_index(level=0, axis=1)

s.columns = s.columns.map('_'.join)
s.reset_index(inplace=True)
s
Out[751]: 
   Machine   Time  Part1_PowerA  Part1_PowerB  Part2_PowerA  Part2_PowerB
0        1  20:30           0.1           0.4           0.9           0.7
1        1  20:31           0.3           0.1           0.2           0.3
2        2  20:30           0.2           0.5          -1.0          -1.0
3        2  20:31           0.8           0.4          -1.0          -1.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pivot` in combination with string formatting for a fairly clean solution:

```py
out = (
    df.pivot(['Machine', 'Time'], 'Part')
    .fillna(-1)
    .sort_index(level=1, axis=1)
)

out.columns = out.columns.map('Part{0[1]}_{0[0]}'.format)
out = out.reset_index()

print(out)
   Machine   Time  Part1_PowerA  Part1_PowerB  Part2_PowerA  Part2_PowerB
0        1  20:30           0.1           0.4           0.9           0.7
1        1  20:31           0.3           0.1           0.2           0.3
2        2  20:30           0.2           0.5          -1.0          -1.0
3        2  20:31           0.8           0.4          -1.0          -1.0
```

---

Alternatively, if you want a method chained solution, you'll need to use `.pipe` to access the current columns values from `.set_axis` so you end up with some extra code bloat:

```
print(
    df.pivot(['Machine', 'Time'], 'Part')
    .fillna(-1)
    .sort_index(level=1, axis=1)
    .pipe(lambda d: 
        d.set_axis(
            d.columns.map('Part{0[1]}_{0[0]}'.format),
            axis='columns'
        )
    )
    .reset_index()
)

   Machine   Time  Part1_PowerA  Part1_PowerB  Part2_PowerA  Part2_PowerB
0        1  20:30           0.1           0.4           0.9           0.7
1        1  20:31           0.3           0.1           0.2           0.3
2        2  20:30           0.2           0.5          -1.0          -1.0
3        2  20:31           0.8           0.4          -1.0          -1.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You may do:

```
df = pd.pivot_table(df, values=['PowerA','PowerB'], index=['Machine', 'Time'], columns='Part')
df.columns = df.columns.to_flat_index()
df.columns = [ 'Part' + str(col[1]) + '_'  + col[0] for col in df.columns]
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.fillna(-1,inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is with [pivot_wider](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_wider) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), that can help with abstracting the reshaping process:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

(df
.pivot_wider(
    index = ['Machine', 'Time'], 
    names_from = 'Part', 
    names_glue = "Part{Part}_{_value}")
.fillna(-1)
)

   Machine   Time  Part1_PowerA  Part2_PowerA  Part1_PowerB  Part2_PowerB
0        1  20:30           0.1           0.9           0.4           0.7
1        1  20:31           0.3           0.2           0.1           0.3
2        2  20:30           0.2          -1.0           0.5          -1.0
3        2  20:31           0.8          -1.0           0.4          -1.0
```

The `names_glue` offers a flexible way to reshape the column names. It uses python's string `format_map` under the hood. The `_value` is a placeholder for the values columns (in this case the `Power` columns). Note that the relevant labels from the dataframe are wrapped in a `{}` - that is `_value` and `Part`.